# VBA String Delimiter

Tags: vba, excel

How can I split a string in VBA after a certain amount of the same delimiter?

For example : `{"Josh","Green"},{"Peter","John"}`.

Here I would like `{"Josh","Green"}` as the first record in an array and `{"Peter","John"}` as the second. I want to avoid parsing the string character by character.

Comment: I think you should close your questions by clicking the checkmark beside the answer that helped you, or comment as to why the answers did not help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, my suggestion:

Replace `},{` with something else before the split, to create a new delimiter.

For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Const c As String = "{""Josh"",""Green""},{""Peter"",""John""}"
    Dim s As String
    Dim v As Variant

    s = Replace(c, "},{", "}#,#{", 1)

    v = Split(s, "#,#")

    Debug.Print v(0)    '{"Josh","Green"}
    Debug.Print v(1)    '{"Peter","John"}
End Sub
```

That will split `s` into a Variant-array `v` with two strings, `v(0)` and `v(1)`, instead of four strings, which you would get if you split the original string with just `,` as a delimiter.